# Laravel 5.8 "Class 'App\Exports\Auth' not found"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I am trying to download records related to authenticated user using [maatwebsite/excel](https://medium.com/maatwebsite/supercharge-your-excel-exports-in-laravel-eb9f74395995) and here is my export:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return Auth::user()->getrecs();
    }
}
```

but when I try to visit the route related to this export I get:

> "Class 'App\Exports\Auth' not found"

how to solve this?

Comment: put `use Auth;` at the top. that all fixed your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `Auth`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return Auth::user()->getrecs();
    }
}
```

**FYI, Now Laravel has released version 7**.